# Изменение последнего столбца всех записей Sql

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Необходимо пройтись по каждому столбцу, считать данные, что-то с ними сделать и сразу занести в последний столбец данной записи. Пробовал так:

```
  private async void CalculateClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;
            SqlCommand sqlRead = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [DATA]", sqlConnection);
            SqlCommand updateDepth = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [DATA] SET [Depth]=@Depth", sqlConnection);
            updateDepth.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Depth", SqlDbType.Float));
            sqlReader = await sqlRead.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            try
            { 
                while (await sqlReader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    int[] values = new int[12];
                    float bill = 100;
                    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        values[i] = sqlReader.GetInt32(i + 2);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        if (values[i] == 0)
                        {
                            for (int j = values[i + 1]; j > 0; --j)
                            {
                                bill *= 0.015F;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    updateDepth.Parameters[0].Value = bill;
                    await updateDepth.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
                UpdateData();
            }
```

В результате в последнем столбце Depth у каждой записи начальное значение bill, то есть 100. C Sql работаю в первый раз, прошу помощи:)

Comment: вот это `UPDATE [DATA] SET [Depth]=@Depth` устанавливает значение `@Depth` для всех строк таблицы. То есть вот тут `await updateDepth.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();` вы перезаписываете каждый раз колонку всей таблицы. Вам наверное надо пересчитать и обновить только ту строку, с которой вы работаете. Для этого надо указать какой то ключ, например `UPDATE [DATA] SET [Depth]=@Depth WHERE Id = @Id` и передавать в команду два параметра, а не один.

Comment: используйте update по номеру строки, типа UPDATE [DATA] SET [Depth]=@Depth and IDRECORD = @Record - которую тоже можно вычислить.